# How to load Product from nid

Tags: drupal, ubercart, drupal-nodes

How Can I load a Product from the db based on the nid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$product = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT * FROM {uc_products} WHERE nid = '%s'", *nid here*));

print_r($product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing a direct db call is an option; however, it is not the Drupal way and does not utilize the benefits of fields, revisions, etc that Drupal's node/CCK system offers.  Since uc_products are nodes in Drupal, simply call:

```
$product = node_load($nid);
```